# Disable dota 2 mega kill announcer?

Tags: dota-2

The voice that screams "Monster kill!" and the like is incredibly annoying. Is there a way to turn it off?

Answer (score 3):

You can install the [Gordon Freeman Announcer](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=141861678) mod. As you know, Mr Freeman is a man of very few words.

Alternatively you can disable (or just turn down) all unit speech, which includes the announcer volume, by changing the unit speech volume slider in the options menu.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the announcer with the console command
`snd_setmixer announcer mute 1.0`.

Answer (score -2):

No, there's no way to turn it off.

Comment: Why downvoted??

Comment: Because that isn't true. Modding the game's announcer files is pretty trivial. I used to play with an NBA Jam mega-kill announcer. Was very fitting. Worst case scenario, you can always mod the announcer files and replace them with silent audio.